# Identify flexible metal tubing and connector

Tags: electrical, plumbing

I need to replace a water-tight tube, but what was used before eludes me. It's from a home made hot water handling system I inherited.

It seems like flexible aluminum conduit, but the ribs are concentric, not a spiral. See first image.[image]

The connector is a stainless threaded nut and washer but, but it seems to be retained by a crimping flat of the tubing's rings.  See second picture.
[image]

So that suggests I can't just replace with flexible conduit. None of the conduit connectors seem to match, either.

Any idea what material this is? Or for what intended usage, so that I could try to find a compatible solution?

Answer (score 3):

Flex tube for connecting a water heater, almost certainly not Aluminum.

Here's an image from Lowes website of a kit with two of them for less than $30 (no affiliation other than occasionally shopping for stuff the orange box does not have at the far less conveniently located blue box.)

[image]

Stainless steel, supposedly. And it's plumbing, not electrical.

Comment: Two of them....hmmm cold water in....hot water out?

Comment: Lacking a magical springwater source inside the heater, that is the usual method.